# Burst Detection in R with Bursts package (Kleinberg)

Tags: r

```
> library(bursts)
> par(mfrow=c(2,1))
> offsets <- c(seq(0, 400, 100), seq(410, 450, 5), seq(451, 470, 2),
+              seq(480, 600, 5), 700, seq(710, 800, 5), 900, 1000)
> bursts <- kleinberg(offsets)
> plot(offsets)
> plot(bursts)
```

Following the demo code from bursts package. I drew a plot below and I just cannot relate the bursts result with the original data. The burst plot indicate there is a high level burst at time 400+, and I just can not see any bursts from the original plot. Can anyone help me understand how to read the burst plot?

[image]

Comment: Is is possible to adapt your code for timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting index as the x and offset as the y, but I think you should switch them.  Try this:

```
plot(offsets,1:length(offsets))
```

[image]